# history expansion not working in script

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

```
rm "1/!(Thursday.tar.gz)"
```

error:

```
rm: cannot remove `1/!(Thursday.tar.gz)': No such file or directory
```

while `rm 1/!(Thursday.tar.gz)` working in terminal

Comment: Show us how your script look like

Comment: Maybe your interactive shell is not the same as your script's shell. Consider installing `zsh` and using it as your login shell, and starting your script with `#! /bin/zsh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include both a proper [shebang line](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and any necessary shell options at the start of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
```

In particular, in Bash, the "[extglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob)" option is necessary for the `!(...)` globbing syntax to work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct/same shell in your script as you use in the terminal.

For example if you are using bash, you can add this to the start of your script to make sure it uses bash as well:

```
#! /bin/bash
```

Same goes for other shells you might use.

Note: `#!` is called 'shebang' and let you pick the shell the script requires, check [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) for more information.